# How to dynamically subclass (or implement) a base class (or an interface)?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I want to test a parametric Abstract Factory Method implementation:

```
public class AbstractChairFactory
{
  public static ChairFactory GetFactory(IChairType type)
  {
    if(type is ChairA)
       ...
    if(type is ChairB)
      ...
    throw new Exception("Unknow type");
  }
}

interface IChairType {}
class ChairA : IChairType
{
}

class ChairB : IChairType
{
}
```

`AbstractChairFactory.GetFactory` method should throw exception when instance of any type rather than of type `IChairType` is passed to it.

One way is to design yet another class `FakeType`:

```
class FakeType : IChairType {}
```

and pass it throgh.

But is there any better way to do so? I mean a way to dynamically implement `IChairType`. Something like this:

```
   IChairType fakeInstance = SomeMagic.GetAFakeVersionOf<IChairType>();

   try
   {
        AbstractChairFactory.GetFactory(fakeInstance);
        Assert.Fail();
   }
   catch
   {

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is Mocking.  There are free frameworks like `Moq` that exist.  There are also `Microsoft Fakes` which is included with certain versions of Visual Studio. And there are commercial products like `TypeMock` that can do this.

To do something like this in Moq, your test might look like this (Assuming that `IChairType` had a method `A` that returns a string):

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var i = new Moq.Mock<IChairType>();
    i.Setup(x => x.A()).Returns("A Faked String");

    var fakedObject = i.Object;
    var result = fakedObject.A();

    Console.WriteLine(result);  // A Faked String
}
```